# SSL error: certificate Chain Complete?

Tags: ssl, certificate, directadmin

I got an email from COMODO.
the file is:

1. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
2. COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
3. COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
4. domain_file_.crt

i set this by directadmin and copy files to private_html folder.

now when i check certificate show error:
[https://www.sslshopper.com](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=varzesh.link)
How can I fix?
tank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not installed SSL correctly on your domain and due to that you are facing this issues, Please add CA bundle while installing SSL for your domain so that you will not get any error with the SSL,

http://www.geotrust.eu/en/support/manuals/directadmin/directadmin/install+certificate/